# Server certificate does NOT include an ID XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm trying to get Apache running on my system using XAMPP, every time I try to start it I get an error:

> 09:28:04  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 09:28:04  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 09:28:04  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another > method.
>
> 09:28:04  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 09:28:04  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 09:28:04  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 09:28:04  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums

I've then opened the error log and it seems like it keeps outputting:

> [ssl:warn] [pid 8516:tid 704] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server ? certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

I then tried to do a little more research on the error and I then discovered that it could be administration issues, so I then ran it as admin but still nothing. Not sure how to proceed with this issue, so I thought I'd ask for help from someone with a little more experience with Apache and XAMPP.

Comment: Have you made a certificate for your project or `htdocs` folder?

Comment: I haven't no, unfortunately I'm only now taking the first steps with using apache and xampp so I'm not sure how I'd go about doing this.

Comment: If you need to use SSL on your localhost then I have a solution - however it's not a quick fix. I wrote a guide to HTTPS and Windows with Apache and there are 20 steps to go through and my guide was as clear and concise as I could make it.

Comment: The first thing to do is to click on the 'Config' button on the XAMPP control panel and see the Apache (httpd.conf) and Apache (httpd-ssl.conf) files. If I remember correctly, the latter file will reference `example.com` - you should be able to change that to your local instance, so if you're using `localhost:443` in your browser, replace `example.com` with `localhost` as a starter. Try that and if you get no joy, revert it. Around line 36 of httpd-ssl.conf I have `Listen 127.0.0.1:443` as that points to my localhost.

Comment: I'm not using anything through my browser as of yet as I haven't been able to get it up and running. I've tried replacing the `example.com` with `localhost` but this didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Are you still getting the same errors after the change that you made?

Comment: Yes the error the window is the same but the error.log isn't updating, unless it isn't writing to it as it's not an error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167800/discussion-between-shaun-bebbers-and-matt-hutch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that a fresh install of XAMPP resolved my error, and I can now run Apache with no errors.